# GetFileTime always returns same time

Tags: windows, winapi, timestamp, usb

I am trying to determine the LastWrite time for a file.
I am using the GetFileTime function, and when I print the the timestamp I get something in hexadecimal.
The I modify the file(text file), using the OS(open it in notepad and add something) and then I close it. In Windows explorer I see the Last Modified field changed, but when I run the program it returns the same timestamp.

Said file is on a USB stick formated to NTFS. Does it have any importance?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Or use [`_stat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) (example code at bottom of page).

Or actually use `GetFileTime()`:

[Retrieving the Last-Write Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How do I use that? It requires an LPVOID as parameter, but I cannot then read the info from it because: "LPVOID not a pointer to object type"

Comment: How do I use GetFileAttributesEx? And how is it different from GetFileTime?

Comment: Please consider using a search engine: http://nogeekhere.blogspot.de/2009/01/how-to-get-last-modified-date-of-file.html

Comment: Kept searching and couldn't find anything. Eventually found something I understood on a different site, something with Origin. Anyway, case solved, thanks. But why didn't my initial method work? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hard to say without taking a look at your source code, but in general it should also work. Here is some sample code using GetFileTime(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RatkinHHK: You probably forgot to check error codes (i.e. return values), and [GetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320.aspx) or [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) failed. However, that's impossible to tell, without seeing the code.